# passportjs TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, passport.js

I've seen others with the same issue and looked at their solutions but I'm not sure if they helped. I can't seem to debug my code with the notes online and simple log statements. I am new to Express and Passport so any help or useful links I would appreciate.

Here is the code, dependencies and the error.

ERROR: passportjs TypeError: undefined is not a function  ->> return done(null, user)  is the line the error is on

Dependencies:

```
"body-parser": "^1.10.2",
"cookie-parser": "~1.3.3",
"express": "~4.11.1",
"express-session": "^1.10.3",
"hjs": "~0.0.6",
"mongodb": "^1.4.40",
"monk": "*",
"morgan": "^1.5.1",
"passport": "^0.2.1",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
"serve-favicon": "^2.2.0",
```

FILE NAME PASSPORT.JS

```
    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({

            // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
            usernameField: 'username',
            passwordField: 'password',
            passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
        },
        function (req, res, email, password, done) {
            var db = req.db;
            var companyName = req.body.companyName;
            var fname = req.body.fname;
            var email = req.body.email;
            var username = req.body.username;
            //var lname = req.body.lname;
            //var phone = req.body.phone;
            var password = req.body.password;

            // Check if any field has been left blank
            console.log('check if fields filled');
            if (fname === '' || companyName === '' || email === '' || username === '' || password === '' ) {
                console.log('Is this working????');
                res.render('business/register', {
                    error: 'You must fill in all fields.',
                    fname: fname,
                    companyName: companyName,
                    email: email,
                    username: username,
                    password: password
                });
            } else {
                console.log('grab data from database');
                var businesses = db.get('businesses');
                var employees = db.get('employees');
                //TODO: Get visitors too
                //var visitors = db.get('visitors');
                //var staff = db.get('staff');
                //var

                // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
                // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
                businesses.findOne({'email': email}, function (err, user) {
                    // if there are any errors, return the error

                    if (err) {
                        return done(err);
                    }

                    // check to see if theres already a user with that email
                    if (user) {
                        console.log('user exists');
                        console.log(user);
                        return done(null, false);
                    } else {

                        // if there is no user with that email
                        // create the user
                        console.log('creating user');
                        // set the user's local credentials
                        password = auth.hashPassword(password);

                        // save the user
                        businesses.insert({
                            email: email,
                            password: password,
                            companyName: companyName,
                            //phone: phone,
                            fname: fname,
                            username: username,
                            //lname: lname,
                            logo: '',
                            walkins: false
                        }, function (err, result) {
                            if (err) {
                                throw err;
                            }

                            var businessID = result._id.toString();

                            employees.insert({
                                business: ObjectId(businessID),
                                password: result.password,
                                //phone: result.phone,
                                fname: result.fname,
                                //lname: result.lname,
                                email: result.email,
                                smsNotify: true,
                                emailNotify: true,
                                admin: true
                            },function(err, user){
                                if (err) {
                                    throw err;
                                }
                                console.log(user);
                                //error is right here
                                return done(null, user);
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    ));`
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: thanks for the guide just started using this site @JasonS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handler callback has an extra `res` argument that isn't valid. Its signature should be:

```
function(req, email, password, done)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works for now. I tried that before and it gave me an issue saying res is not defined below. I must have messed something up along the way to get that issue.

  res.render('business/register', {
                    error: 'You must fill in all fields.',
                    fname: fname,
                    companyName: companyName,
                    email: email,
                    username: username,
                    password: password
                });

Comment: You shouldn't send back responses from the Passport handler. Instead, use  the redirect and flash message functionality that Passport offers instead.